# syntax error or access violation 1064 pdo in a query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I receive via URL a string which is an INSERT or DELETE query. Once received, I have to insert data in the mysql database.
The url is something like this:

> www.mysite.com/page.php?query=INSERT INTO orders (IDCliente, IDOrdine, DTOrdine) VALUES ('0569', 2593, '19-09-2018')

My simple script:

```
include_once('../config/database.php');
include_once('../config/core.php');

$id=isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : die('ERROR: Empty string'); 

$id = '"'.$_GET['query'].'"';

try {

    $stmt = $con->prepare($id);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        die('Unable to delete record.');
    } catch(PDOException $exception) {
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now, if I use

```
 $stmt = $con->prepare($id)
```

I get an

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

but if I use the query straight into the prepare statement

```
  $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (IDCliente, IDOrdine, DTOrdine) VALUES ('0569', 2593, '19-09-2018')");
```

in this way, works! 
I have checked the double quote (added into the `$id = '"'.$_GET['query'].'"';`) and everything seems ok.I also tried the query into phpmyadmin and is correct

I'm trying to learn PDO, thanks for the patience.

Note: **For all, I explain. This query with data comes ONLY from a business software. No user can use it, and there's no other way to interface it with the website.**

Comment: Dump `$id`. Check its contents before execution.

Comment: You don't need to add quotes to the string from the query line.  BUT this (as already pointed out) is a very bad and insecure idea!

Comment: I agree with Mulder, and directly running entire SQL statements coming from the outside is _worse_ than normal SQL injection; it is leaving your database wide open for total destruction.  To your question: The single quotes in the insert query parameter may be causing problems, and also you should not be placing double quotes around the insert query.  But, _don't_ use this approach!  Instead, just let users on the outside pass in _parameters_ which you then bind to your prepared statement.

Comment: `www.mysite.com/page.php?query=SELECT * FROM users` or `www.mysite.com/page.php?query=DROP TABLE orders`   -- Whoops

Comment: For all, I explain. This query with data comes from a business software. No user can use it, and there's no other way to interface it with the website.

Comment: @Ogum you could use `API` instead of this disaster as they said in the comments above

Comment: @ogum There's always a way. You just don't see it yet. Security by ignorance is the worst type of security.

Comment: At first it worked with the old mysql_query. I'm just updating the script (highly insecure, i know) but the client doesn't want to spend money so I have to do it this way and it has always worked without intrusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first implement an api , not this spaggeti.
secound try this :

```
include_once('../config/database.php');
include_once('../config/core.php');

$id=isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : die('ERROR: Empty string'); 

try {

    $stmt = $con->prepare($id);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        die('Unable to delete record.');
    }

    }   catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: query passing through url works just fine , maybe problem is from your database or core , are they imported currctly?

Comment: Yes, i solved deleting $id = '"'.$_GET['query'].'"'; and thanks for the offense

Comment: no offence , :) . when you code like this , soon you will loose controll over it and everything will be twisted. mark this answer as correct to close this Q. hope best